# Converting an ODE into a system of first order ODEs

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I convert the following third order ODE to a system of first order
ODEs in the form $\dot{x} = P(t)x + g(t)$.

$$\dddot{y} + t\dot{y} + e^{t}y = \sin(t).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x=(y,\dot{y},\ddot{y})$. Then you want a matrix $A$ such that

$$
\dot{x} = Ax + b,
$$

where $A$ and $b$ are both functions of $t$. It is straightforward to see that

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-e^t & -t & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
b = (0,0,\sin{t})
$$

will work; the first two rows give the identities $\dot{y}=\dot{y}$ and $\ddot{y}=\ddot{y}$, the last gives the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, introduce new variables. Define $X\equiv y$ and
$$\dot X\equiv Y\\\dot Y\equiv Z\\
\dot Z\,=\,\sin(t)\,-\,tY\,-\,e^tX$$
which is what you were looking for.